# Add Default value in dynamic antd form

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, default-value

I Want to ad default 2 first name and last name in the following dynamic antd form in react . How can I accomplish it to have default rows when page is loaded .[Code for the dynamic form](https://codesandbox.io/s/wh0hz)

Answer (score 0):

Add `initialValues` into `<Form>` would create default row

```
<Form
  name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
  onFinish={onFinish}
  autoComplete="off"
  initialValues={{ users: [{first: "hello", last: "world"}] }}
>
```